# Taxonomy view - showing term searched for in header

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've enabled the Taxonomy View template and used the taxonomy term page module to specify this view should be used when clicking on one of the taxonomy terms.

The page itself is working & looking great, but I'm struggling to show the vocabulary and term used in the header region.

Current view setup:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j38nsznel93eoz3/Screenshot%202014-10-22%2022.56.28.png?dl=0

I'm hoping to use one view for all the different vocabularies - but wanted to show in the header e.g.

All articles tagged [author name]  - where the vocabulary used is 'author'

or

All articles tagged [project] - where the vocabulary used is 'project'

Anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: What is in the header region? Do you get something or nothing at all? Also if you want to use use tokens in your text, make sure you've loaded them as fields first. (I see no field related to project)

Comment: It was showing just a result count - but thank you, with this and the answer below from @awasson I got it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Neograph734 has eluded to the answer here.

If you add a field for taxonomy term name but don't display it (exclude from display), you can add a header field of type "Global Text" and render the term name from the collection of tokens that are representing the fields.

Comment: Thanks - bit of fiddling this morning and it's running nicely.